# I have a simple android app to insert data into a wamp database server. But the information doesn't add in the db. Here's my code:

Tags: java, php, android

Here is my Register.php

```
<?php

require "init.php";

$name=$_POST["user"];
$user_name = $_POST["user_name"];
$user_pass = $_POST["user_pass"];

$sql_query = "insert into user_info values('$user','$user_name','$user_pass');";

if(mysqli_query($con,$sql_query)) {
    //echo "Data Insertion Success...";
} else { 
    //echo "Data Insertion Error...".mysqli_error($con);
}
```

Here is the Register Activity.

```
public class Register extends Activity {

    String naam,username,pass;

    EditText new_user_pass;
    EditText new_user_name;
    EditText name;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

        new_user_name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.new_user_name);
        new_user_pass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.new_user_pass);
        name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);

    }

    public void userReg(View view)
    {
        naam = name.getText().toString();
        username = new_user_name.getText().toString();
        pass = new_user_pass.getText().toString();

        String method;
        method="register";
        Backend backEnd = new Backend(this);
        backEnd.execute(method,naam,username,pass);
        finish();
    }
}
```

Here is the back end activity.

```
public class Backend extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String> {

    Context ctx;
    Backend(Context ctx)
    {

        this.ctx=ctx;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String reg_url="http://192.168.0.7/app/register.php";
        String login_url="http://192.168.0.7/app/register.php";
        String method = params[0];

        if(method.equals("register")){

            String naam=params[1];
            String username=params[2];
            String pass=params[3];

            try {
                URL url = new URL (reg_url);
                HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
                httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                OutputStream OS = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
                BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(OS,"UTF-8"));
                String data = URLEncoder.encode("user", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(naam,"UTF-8") + "&"+
                URLEncoder.encode("user_name", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(username,"UTF-8") +"&"+
                URLEncoder.encode("user_pass", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(pass,"UTF-8");
                bufferedWriter.write(data);
                bufferedWriter.flush();
                bufferedWriter.close();
                OS.close();
                InputStream IS = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                IS.close();
                return "Registration Success";
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return reg_url;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        Toast.makeText(ctx,result,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }


    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate();
    }
}
```

Comment: `catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();`. How will the user of your app know if there was an exception? Return a string with error message. So it will be displayed by the toast in on post execute.

Comment: `InputStream IS = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            IS.close();
            return "Registration Success";`. You are not reading from the input stream. And you blindly return a succes string. The php script echos a succes of failure string. Read them from the inputstream and display by that same toast.